# Hover fadeIn, repeating

Tags: jquery, hover, fadein

When a user hovers over div1: -

- div1 and div2's contents fadeout
- div1 loads some new content
- div2 fades in div1s existing content

This is where I want this to stop.

However, when the new contents of div1 load, the hover event triggers again, and this continues.

how can i make it so after the initial hover event, the hover event wont occur again  until the user has removed the cursor and hovered again on div1?

hope this makes sense, cheers in advance!

```
$('document').ready(function () {

    //For each small block
    $('#div1').hover(function () {

        var thisWish = $(this).html();
        var nextWish = $('#wishy1').html();

        //Fade the small block out bring in a new wish
        $(this).fadeOut(1200, function () {
            $(this).html(nextWish).fadeIn(1200, function () {

            });
        });

        //Fade the large block and and bring in the small blocks wish
        $('#div2').fadeOut(1200, function () {
            $('#div2').html(thisWish).fadeIn(1200, function () {

            });
        });
    }, 
    function () {
        // hover out
    });
});
```

Comment: Please could you post your HTML? (Or a simplified version of it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not using the second event of the *hover*, use *mouseover* instead:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    //For each small block
    $('#div1').mouseover(function(){
        var thisWish = $(this).html();
        var nextWish = $('#wishy1').html();
        //Fade the small block out bring in a new wish
        $(this).fadeOut(1200, function(){
            $(this).html(nextWish).fadeIn(1200, function(){
            });
        });
        //Fade the large block and and bring in the small blocks wish
        $('#div2').fadeOut(1200, function(){
            $('#div2').html(thisWish).fadeIn(1200, function(){
            });
        });
    }

})
```